# SQL lookup table with multiple IDs per row

Tags: mysql

I'm using the Retrosheet baseball play-by-play database to help me learn SQL (using mySQL). It has a table called games, which gives general information about all the games played: date, stadium, teams, score, etc.  It also gives information about players, like starting pitchers, lineups, umpires, etc.  However, all people are labeled using IDs.  I have a lookup table that matches all IDs to first and last names.

If I wanted to select * from the games database matching a specific game, but I wanted to return the names from the ID table instead of the IDs, is there a way to do that?

To be more specific, lets say I wanted to select game_ID, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_start_pit_id, away_start_pit_id from games.  What I would like to have is both pitcher's real names instead of id.

Comment: Have you studied table joins? If not, please read up on this topic.  Joins are a fundamental aspect of SQL and are covered in every SQL tutorial.

Comment: I had tried joins, but didn't know how I could return more than one name, the answer below was what I didn't know how to do.

Comment: If you were to select BaseballGame, StartingPlayerName, Team, Position where team ='home' you would get 9 rows. That is how SQL works. Normally putting more than one player on the same row is a Presentation Layer responsibility. But in SQL, it can be done; to get more than one player on the same row in such a query, you'd have to do advanced SQL using PIVOT.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is a table called "pitchers" with fields id, first_name, last_name (and others)

You would do a simple join.

```
select game_id, home_team_id,home_team_id, away_team_id,
   home_team_pitcher.first_name, home_team_pitcher.last_name,
   away_team_pitcher.first_name, away_team_pitcher.last_name
   from games
   join pitchers as home_team_pitcher on pitchers.id = home_start_pit_id
   join pitchers as away_team_pitcher on pitcher.id = away_start_pit_id
```